# Matlab: Editing the lhsnorm() function for Latin Hypercube

Tags: matlab, random, normal-distribution

I am attempting to edit the lhsnorm function so that I can obtain Latin Hypercube sample from a Normally distributed set of data.

The lhsnorm function is as follows:

```
function [X,z] = lhsnorm(mu,sigma,n,dosmooth)
%LHSNORM Generate a latin hypercube sample with a normal distribution

z1 = mvnrnd(mu,sigma,numel(z));
%%%%%%%%Is it possible for me to change this to a univariate distribution 
% without affecting the rest of the code ?????

% Find the ranks of each column
p = length(mu);
x = zeros(size(z),class(z));
for i=1:p
   x(:,i) = rank(z(:,i));
end

% Get gridded or smoothed-out values on the unit interval
if (nargin<4) || isequal(dosmooth,'on')
   x = x - rand(size(x));
else
   x = x - 0.5;
end
x = x / n;

% Transform each column back to the desired marginal distribution,
% maintaining the ranks (and therefore rank correlations)
for i=1:p
   x(:,i) = norminv(x(:,i),mu(i), sqrt(sigma(i,i)));
end
X = x;

function r=rank(x)

% Similar to tiedrank, but no adjustment for ties here
[sx, rowidx] = sort(x);
r(rowidx) = 1:length(x);
r = r(:);
```

I am editing the code as is shown below:

```
function [X] = lhsnorm_sid(z,dosmooth)

[muhat,sigmahat] = normfit(z);

z = z';
% Find the ranks of each column
p = length(muhat);
x = zeros(size(z),class(z));
s = size(z);
n = s(1,1);

for i=1:p
   x(:,i) = rank(z(:,i));
end

if (nargin<4) || isequal(dosmooth,'on')
   x = x - rand(size(x));
else
   x = x - 0.5;
end
x = x / n;

for i=1:p
   x(:,i) = norminv(x(:,i),muhat(i), sqrt(sigmahat(i,i)));
end
X = x;

function r=rank(x)

[sx, rowidx] = sort(x);
r(rowidx) = 1:length(x);
r = r(:);
```

**However, I end up with Latin Hypercube values which are way off what is expected. I also tried directly substituting z with d(1,:) which contains a Normally distributed set of data, however the Latin Hypercube I obtained did not contain any of the values in d(1,:)**.

Thanks

Comment: Did you take a look at muhat and sigmahat? Do they look like the mu and sigma you used to generate d? normfit gives an estimation of mu and sigma, however the sigma you used in your previous question is really small and normfit can fail to give a precise estimation.

Comment: @Etienne Yes. That works thank you very much. Do you know how I would calculate the probability of a certain number in the Latin Hypercube? Would it just be 1 divided by the number of elements in the array? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I dont know the answer but, maybe someone on  http://math.stackexchange.com/ know it.